# Diablo III Ancient Legendary drop rate

Tags: diablo-iii

Now that ancient legendaries have been introduced, a lot of end-game is trying to acquire ancient legendary versions of your legendary gear for the improved stats.

[image: An ancient legendary Cindercoat has 20-50% improved stats across the board]

Assuming I only run greater rifts, what's the drop chance/rate for an ancient legendary based on my greater rift level? Is there a way to improve my chances other raising my greater rift level, like increasing my magic find?

Comment: I have no source (so not answering) but I believe any legendary/set has a flat 5% chance to be ancient.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill That seems to match Frank's 1 in 20 rate for crafting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [2.1.2 patch notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/17561388/patch-212-now-live-1-13-2015#items) that introduced Ancient legendaries stated that they could only drop from Torment I and higher:

> - Ancient items can now drop at Torment I or higher
>
>   - The drop chance will increase with each Torment level

Based on the [Diablo Wiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Legendary#Frequency), the chances go from 1.5% for Torment I, up to 10% for T6.

> The odds increase on higher levels of Torment, from around 1.5% on Torment 1 up to 10% on Torment 6 (from monster drops).

Note that this doesn't include Kadala or crafting; those chances are not known, but are probably a set rate to preclude doing so in T6 to maximize chances.

Comment: and either its lower for crafting or I just have horrible horrible luck with them.

Comment: I think I got roughly 1 in 20, when I was going for Aughild's upgrades.  It took a bit, and I didn't record them, but that seems about right; somewhere in the middle of T1 and T6.

Comment: Kadala is purely RNG.

Comment: @Virusboy Yes, but there's still a rate at which she will award legendaries, and ancients; RNG doesn't work in a vacuum.

Comment: I dont think her awarding system is a vacuum, I think the award system is the RNG

Comment: @Virusboy You're misunderstanding how RNG works.  In order for Kadala to award an ancient, she has to have some value, somewhere, in order for her to do that.  Even if that value is 1%, it's still a value the RNG has to meet in order for an ancient to be awarded.  The question of whether she awards ancients isn't in question; it's what that specific rate is.  RNG works off of systems; we don't know the specific value, but we do know that it is a non-zero value.

Comment: How about greater rifts? As far as I know, greater rift level 26 is equivalent to Torment VI, so does that mean that any greater rift level 26 or higher is capped 10% ancient legendary rate?

Comment: @SadlyNot I have been unable to find any source for greater rift drop rates.  My gut says that T6 is the highest it will get, but I have nothing to corroborate that.